# C# /Javascript /ASP.NET - Changing DIV Contents From A Child Page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, http

Basically I have a masterpage defining the basic layout of the website. What I am trying to do is, in the child page change the contents of a div. I know I can use this:

```
//((HtmlGenericControl)this.Page.Master.Master.FindControl("friends")).InnerHtml = "";
```

But I can't put tags in this for example if I wanted to change the div and insert an unordered list.

How can I do this and if you could post an example I'd appreciate it. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expose div as a server side control like PlaceHolder and Add control to it by `div.Controls.Add(control);` at serverside code of child forms.

Comment: Can I change the div by adding something like:

<ul>
              <li><a href="#">f</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">e</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">d</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">c</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
            </ul>

Comment: you can do like this , remember you can always use write any html control by using string appends. but you have to use Controls.Add to make it manage its state during postbacks.

Comment: How do I do a string append with classes? like if I want to include a  <div class="optionsMusic"></class> ?

Comment: you can create like String s = "<div class=\"optionsMusic\"></class>"

Answer (score 0):

```
 HtmlGenericControl div = (HtmlGenericControl)Page.FindControl("<<div id>>");
 HtmlGenericControl ul = HtmlGenericControl("ul")
 HtmlGenericControl liToAdd = null;
 HtmlGenericControl linkToAdd = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            liToAdd = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
            linkToAdd = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
            linkToAdd.InnerText = "demo";
            linkToAdd.Attributes.Add("href", "");
            liToAdd.Controls.Add(linkToAdd);
            ul.Controls.Add(liToAdd);


        }
            div.Controls.Add(ul);
```